# /usr/bin/find: cannot build its arguments dynamically

Tags: bash, find, interactive

The following command works as expected interactively, in a terminal.

```
$ find . -name '*.foo' -o -name '*.bar'
./a.foo
./b.bar
$
```

**However**, if I do this, I get no results!

```
$ ftypes="-name '*.foo' -o -name '*.bar'"
$ echo $ftypes
-name '*.foo' -o -name '*.bar'
$ find . $ftypes
$
```

My understanding was/is that `$ftypes` would get expanded by `bash` before `find` got a chance to run. In which case, the `ftypes` approach should also have worked.

What is going on here?

Many thanks in advance.

PS: I have a need to dynamically build a list of file types (the `ftypes` variable above) to be given to `find` later in a script.

Comment: The single quotes in `"... -name '*.foo'` remain in the interpolated value. If you want `ftypes` to be a variable (not necessarily a good idea anyway) try with just `... -name *.foo` - the double quotes preve

Comment: @triplee no quotes around `*.foo` would result in expanded list of files which will be passed to `find`. I anyway tried what you said, and got this error: `find: paths must precede expression Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: That is not at all my experience.  `touch fnord.foo ick.bar none.svch; ftypes="-name *.foo -o -name *.bar"; find . $ftypes` does exactly what I expect.

Comment: Try this (with 2 .foo files): `touch fnord.foo another.foo ick.bar none.svch; ftypes="-name *.foo -o -name *.bar"; find . $ftypes`.

Comment: Right you are.  I guess `eval` is the best option then.

Comment: I still appreciate your "'a.foo'" clarification. I tried to upvote it, but you deleted your response apparently.

Comment: Thanks (-:  Yeah, I ended up removing my, er, contributions when I couldn't improve on the answers provided by others.  Still perhaps worth mentioning that `set -x` helps see what the shell actually does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both answers so far have recommended using `eval`, but that has a well-deserved reputation for causing bugs.  Here's an example of the sort of bizarre behavior you can get with this:

```
$ touch a.foo b.bar "'wibble.foo'"
$ ftypes="-name '*.foo' -o -name '*.bar'"
$ eval find . $ftypes
./b.bar
```

Why didn't it find the file ./a.foo?  It's because of exactly how that `eval` command got parsed.  bash's parsing goes something like this (with some irrelevant steps left out):

1. bash looks for quotes first (none found -- yet).
2. bash substitutes variables (but doesn't go back and look for quotes in the substituted values -- this is what lead to the problem in the first place).
3. bash does wildcard matching (in this case it looks for files matching `'*.foo'` and `'*.bar'` -- note that it hasn't parsed the quotes, so it just treats them as part of the filename to match -- and finds `'wibble.foo'` and substitutes it for `'*.foo'`).  After this the command is roughly `eval find . -name "'wibble.foo'" -o "'*.bar'"`.  BTW, if it had found multiple matches things would've gotten even sillier by the end.
4. bash sees that the command on the line is `eval`, and runs the whole parsing process over on the rest of the line.
5. bash does quote matching again, this time finding two single-quoted strings (so it'll skip most parsing on those parts of the command).
6. bash looks for variables to substitute and wildcards to matching, etc, but there aren't any in the unquoted sections of the command.
7. Finally, bash runs `find`, passing it the arguments ".", "-name", "wibble.foo", "-o", "-name", and "*.bar".
8. `find` finds one match for "*.bar", but no match for "wibble.foo".  It never even knows you wanted it to look for "*.foo".

So what can you do about this?  Well, in this particular case adding strategic double-quotes (`eval "find . $ftypes"`) would prevent the spurious wildcard substitution, but in general it's best to avoid `eval` entirely.  When you need to build commands, an array is a much better way to go (see [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more discussion):

```
$ ftypes=(-name '*.foo' -o -name '*.bar')
$ find . "${ftypes[@]}"
./a.foo
./b.bar
```

Note that you can also build the options bit by bit:

```
$ ftypes=(-name '*.foo')
$ ftypes+=(-o -name '*.bar')
$ ftypes+=(-o -name '*.baz')
```

Comment: **Go** r **d** on, appreciate your taking the time to explain so wonderfully, elaborating on `eval`, and last but not the least, your pointer to the Bash FAQ item. I had chosen the `eval`-based solution earlier, but now, I will re-edit my code and go with your more elegant array-based solution. *PS: Please upvote the question, if you can.*

Answer (score 2):

Simply prefix the line with `eval` to force the shell to expand and parse the command:

```
eval find . $ftypes
```

Without the `eval`, the `'*.foo'` is passed on literally instead of just `*.foo` (that is, the `'` are suddenly considered to be part of the filename, so `find` is looking for files that start with a single quote and have an extension of `foo'`).

Comment: Your solution works, and explanation somewhat makes sense. But I don't fully get it: Why, just why, should `'` be 'suddenly' part of filename when `bash` is supposed to expand `$ftypes` and pass its 5, space-separated string components to `find` as arguments, namely: `-name`, `'*.foo'`, `-o`, `-name`, and `'*.bar'` much as would happen in an interactive session?

Comment: When you `eval` the single quotes are evaluated.  If you just interpolate without `eval`, the single quotes in the value of `$ftypes` are interpolated verbatim, not evaluated (and removed by the evaluation logic).

Comment: @jfgagne: as per the discussion above, that does not work if there are multiple matches in the current directory, as they will be expanded when `$ftypes` is interpolated.  (I didn't realize this at first, and it kind of sucks IMHO, but that's the way it is.)

Comment: @Harry: If you type `foo 'bar'` then the shell evaluates the `'` and calls the command `foo`, with the argument `bar` (without the single quotes). But if you do `t="'bar'" ; foo $bar"` the shell will actually pass `'bar'` to command `foo`. You can easily check by replacing `foo` with `echo`: `echo 'bar' ; t="'bar'" ; echo $t ; eval echo $t`. The point of `eval` is to *evaluate* the previously expanded line, so this time the single quotes get eaten by the shell  like we want it. Also try this with `t='$PATH'` for fun.

Comment: @DarkDust thanks for your responses. Have upvoted all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that since $ftypes a single quoted value, find does see it as a single argument.

One way around it is:

```
$ eval find . $ftypes
```

Comment: No, it's double quoted. The problem is that the single quotes remain in the expansion.