# bash `find` escaping

Tags: bash, escaping, find

I need to find all of the TIFFs in a directory, recursively, but ignore some artifacts (basically all hidden files) that also happen to end with "`.tif`". This command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.tif' ! -name '.*'
```

works exactly how I want it on the command line, but inside a bash script it doesn't find anything. I've tried replacing `!` with `-and -not` and--I think--just about every escaping permutation I can think of and/or recommended by the googleshpere, e.g.  `.\*`, leaving out single quotes, etc. Obviously I'm missing something, any help is appreciated.

EDIT: here's the significant part of the script; the directory it's doing the find on is parameterized, but I've been debugging with it hard-coded; it makes no difference:

```
#!/bin/bash
RECURSIVE=1
DIR=$1

#get the absolute path to $DIR
DIR=$(cd $DIR; pwd)

FIND_CMD="find $DIR -type f -name '*.tif' ! -name '.*'"
if [ $RECURSIVE == 1 ]; then
    FIND_CMD="$FIND_CMD -maxdepth 1"
fi

for in_img in $($FIND_CMD | sort); do
    echo $in_img # for debugging
    #stuff
done
```

Comment: please include an excerpt from your script

Comment: Are you calling the script from the directory that contains the `.tiff` files?

Comment: What is the working directory of your script? That's where the `find` command is looking for files matching '*.tif'.

Comment: Both versions seem to work for me.

Comment: What happens if you remove everything after `.`? Does it still not find anything?

Comment: The ` ! -name '.*'` part of the command seems to be the culprit; when I take that away it works as expected (except of course that the hidden `.*.tif` files I'm trying to filter out are still there).

Comment: Thanks @pb2q for asking me to post the code; made me realize that it must have had to do with having the expression stored in a var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was related to having the expression stored in a variable. The solution was to use `eval`, which of course would be the right thing to do anyway. Everything is the same as above except at the start of the for loop:

```
for in_img in $(eval $FIND_CMD | sort); do
    #stuff
done
```

Comment: I'll strongly recommend against using `eval` this way, as it can cause some [truly bizarre bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308606/usr-bin-find-cannot-build-its-arguments-dynamically/9322047#9322047).  You're better off storing the command in an array as described in that link (or not storing it at all).  Also, see [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

To not find hidden files you can use the following:

```
 find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -name "*.tif"
```

It checks the filename and doesn't show (! in the parenthesis) the files beginning with a dot, which are the hidden files.

Comment: Same problem, though thanks for the alternative. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm building the expression and storing it in a variable.