# Convert function arguments from upper to lowercase in bash

Tags: bash, case-sensitive, tr

I'm trying to make a convenience function to fix issues when I accidentally have my caps locks on and am trying to run some case-sensitive tools.

e.g. I occasionally find myself typing `MAKE DEBUG` instead of `make debug`.

What I have now is pretty straightforward: `alias MAKE="make"` and editing the makefiles to duplicate the rules, e.g. `DEBUG: debug`.

I'd prefer a solution that works on the arguments, without having to modify the tools involved.

Comment: you actually use that caps lock key?  impressive ;-)

Comment: I find myself using a lot of libraries that really love to DEFINE_EVERYTHING_IN_CAPS.

Comment: That really is impressive.  Me, I just hurt my hands a lot by contorting my fingers to hold down shift while typing REALLY_LONG_NAMES_OF_VARIABLES_OR_WHATEVER.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using GNU sed

If you just want everything in your makefile to be in lowercase, you can use GNU sed to lowercase the whole thing:

```
sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' Makefile
```

You could also build a sed script that's a little more discriminating, but the [\L replacement escape](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) is your friend.

#### Using tr

Since you tagged your question with tr, you might also want a tr solution. It's a little more cumbersom, since tr won't do in-place translations, but you could shuffle temp files or use sponge from *moreutils*. For example:

```
tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' < Makefile | sponge Makefile
```

Answer (score 1):

This involves a script, but avoids the Ctrl-D issue of my earlier attempt:

For each command, an alias like

```
alias MAKE="casefixer make"
```

And then the following file, which I've created at `/usr/local/bin/casefixer`:

```
#!/bin/bash
command=`echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`       # convert 1st arg to lowercase, it's the command to invoke
shift                                                # remove 1st arg from $*
$command `echo "$*" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`    # convert arguments to lowercase, and invoke the command with them
```

Answer (score 1):

Playing on @Clayton Hughes' `casefixer` solution, here's a solution that'll handle funny things like spaces in arguments (which `$*` messes up):

```
casefixer() { eval "$(printf "%q " "$@" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"; }
alias MAKE='casefixer make'
```

Note: `eval` is a fairly dangerous thing, with a well-deserved reputation for causing [really bizarre bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308606/usr-bin-find-cannot-build-its-arguments-dynamically/9322047#9322047).  In this case, however, the combination of double-quoting and encoding the command and its arguments with %q *should* prevent trouble.  At least, I couldn't find a case where it did anything unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, though it's not perfect:

```
alias MAKE="make `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]`"
```

it works, but has the unfortunate problem that I need to press Ctrl-D to send an EOF before anything starts executing.

Answer (score 0):

The `readline` command "downcase-word" (bound to `M-u` by default) is worth mentioning here. Suppose you typed "MAKE DEBUG". If you catch it before hitting return, you can move the cursor to the beginning of the line with `C-a`. (Otherwise, bring the command back first, using the up arrow). Then, each time you hit `M-u`, the word immediately after the cursor will be changed to lowercase, and the cursor will move to the beginning of the next word.

It's a little laborious, and I don't see a way to lowercase the entire line at once. Perhaps someone can improve on this.

Comment: `M-9M-l` (letter ell) will downcase the next 9 words. `M-99M-l` will downcase the next 99. `M--M-l` will downcase the previous one word. `M--3M-l` (release `Alt` before pressing 3 if you're using it instead of `Esc`) the previous 3. `M-u` is bound to `upcase-word` by default at least on my system.

Comment: I have to admit my ignorance here.  What does the `X-x` syntax mean? How would I enter it?