# Executing bash line(command) that contains redirection characters

Tags: linux, bash

How can I execution a bash line(command) that contains the redirection characters?
For instance, the following line can't be execution.

```
home>CMD="ls -l > out"
home>$CMD
ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access out: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`eval $CMD` will do what you want.

Comment: `eval` is a bug magnet, and should be avoided whenever possible. If you must use it, at least double-quote the argument (i.e. `eval "$CMD"`) to avoid the [really bizarre behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308606/usr-bin-find-cannot-build-its-arguments-dynamically/9322047#9322047) that can come from having the command run through extra levels of parsing.

Answer (score 4):

You could use eval, but it is not recommended. If the purpose of storing the command in a variable is to execute it multiple times, it is better to use a function.

Example:

```
dols() {
    ls -l > out
}

dols
```

See also: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)