# assign incomplete command to variable / bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm stuck with a rather silly bash script:

```
CMD="get database" /   #embedded,specific platform command
DATA="tree path Uo5 Uu7"

custom_command='grep -i Arte | awk -F '[:]' '{print $2}'
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
VAR=`$CMD "show data $DATA" | $custom_command`   <--not working
VAR=`$CMD "show data $DATA" | grep -i Arte | awk -F '[:]' '{print $2}'` <--working
```

Using $custom_command breaks the script. How can i use $custom_command to VAR?

I use custom_command to avoid using the same string over and over again. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
custom_command="awk -F':' '/Arte/ {print \$2}'"
var=$(eval "$CMD 'show data $DATA' | $custom_command")
```

OR else without `eval`:

```
custom_command="/Arte/ {print \$2}"
var=$("$CMD" 'show data $DATA' | awk -F':' "$custom_command")
```

- You aren't actually supplying any input file/data to your grep command
- However there is no real need of grep here since awk can handle search part also

Comment: Thanks, but actually the command is bigger, just posted a shortcut.
So i really need to have the custom command inside a variable..that's the big issue. (i will use your way, to cut it shorter - by the way :) )
You think that i could just use the custom command and then add a < having as input this one: < $CMD "show data $DATA"

Comment: I want $custom_command, not $CMD  ;)
Pipe does not work for this:
grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: awk: No such file or directory
grep: '[=,]': No such file or directory
grep: '{print: No such file or directory
grep: $2}'|: No such file or directory
grep: sort: No such file or directory
grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: grep: No such file or directory
grep: [0-9]: No such file or directory

Comment: You can name your variable whatever you want and my answer doesn't change part. My answer is only for fixing your grep and doing that in awk itself.

Comment: If you post your script in your question I can investigate and suggest.

Comment: i edited my initial question to make it more clear! I want to replace the second part of VAR with a string variable!

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to assign commands to variables in `bash`. You want to write functions.

```
custom_command() {
    grep -i Arte | awk -F '[:]' '{print $2}'   
}
```

Comment: Indeed. i tried that but i don't know how to use the function to the output..:/

Comment: Just like any other command. `... | custom_command` will do. BTW `$CMD` also should be a function.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks..!!
Now is there a special reason to use functions instead of "eval" below?? ;)
Which is the most "elegant" way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308606/usr-bin-find-cannot-build-its-arguments-dynamically/9322047#9322047) for a example. If you're using the same command over and over, I'd use a function instead -- that's what they're for. Also, see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more discussion and options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do eval. Something like:

```
FINAL_CMD="$CMD show data $DATA | $custom_command"
VAR=$(eval $FINAL_CMD)
```

Or to adapt it more to your question, try:

```
VAR=`$CMD "show data $DATA" | eval $custom_command`
```